# pandas DataFrame create,access,append MultiIndex with different Column types - SQL table style

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, multi-index

I thought by using the huge pandas.DataFrame library it should be pretty straight forward to do all the standard stuff you can do with an SQL table .. but after looking into many options I still haven't found a good working solution.

Requirements:

- table with a 4 columns with different data types (uint32, string,...) , 3 off them should work as index
- many (>10k) additional columns of type int8
- initially I had the idea to add rows and columns dynamically, but that turned out to be very slow (using df.at[row, col] = y)
- I ended up creating a DataFrame with a few columns with different types and join it with another large DataFrame created from a numpy array with elements of type uint8
- ... that looked quite good, but now nothing works to access, add or set array elements using the index

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import pandas as pd

  # create DataFrame

  idx_names = ['A','B','C']
  col_names = ['y']
  df = pd.DataFrame(columns = idx_names + col_names)

  # create DataFrame from numpy array

  npa = np.zeros((5,10),dtype=np.uint8)
  dfa = pd.DataFrame(npa)

  # add DataFrames column-wise

  t = pd.concat([df,dfa], axis=1)

  # set index columns

  t.set_index(idx_names,inplace=True)
  ```

---

```
               y  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
A   B   C                                     
NaN NaN NaN  NaN  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
        NaN  NaN  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
        NaN  NaN  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
        NaN  NaN  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
        NaN  NaN  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Now I would like to set values in the columns (y,0, ...9) by providing an index.
If the index is not already available it should be added to the table.

```
t( (t['A']='US',t['B']='CA',t['C']='SFO') , 'y') = "IT"
t( (t['A']='US',t['B']='CA',t['C']='LA' ) , '1') = 255
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you expect to happen in contrast to what actually happens? Do you get any errors? What is your final question

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have a new question...

Comment: try this: `t.loc[('US','CA','SFO'), 'y'] = 'IT'`

Comment: The remaining problems are (and that's why I came up with the idea to create first a numpy array) that
a) new rows and colums contain NaNs, so I can't increment the value by +=1 (without a lenghty "if NaN then .. else ... " (what I wanted to avoid for performnce reasons)
b) I lost the type of the data elements , they are not uint8 anymore (.. and I have millions of them)

Comment: if I use again (see initial question) "t = pd.concat([df,dfa], axis=1)" then zeros and uint8 type is maintained, but with the same code I then get "    raise KeyError('%s not in index' % objarr[mask])
KeyError: "['US','CA','SFO'] not in index"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following multi-index DataFrame:

```
In [44]: df
Out[44]:
       d
a b c
0 0 1  1
4 4 4  3
0 1 4  4
2 6 1  3
0 1 3  6
```

and you want to add the following 2D array as 10 new columns:

```
In [45]: data
Out[45]:
array([[ 0.76021523,  0.92020945,  0.20205685,  0.03888115,  0.41166093,  0.67509844,  0.15351393,  0.00926459,  0.09297956,  0.72930072],
       [ 0.38229582,  0.88199428,  0.08153019,  0.08367272,  0.88548522,  0.50332168,  0.94652147,  0.83362442,  0.219431  ,  0.09399454],
       [ 0.43743926,  0.79447959,  0.18430898,  0.31534202,  0.63229928,  0.80921108,  0.76570853,  0.09890863,  0.33604303,  0.92960105],
       [ 0.6561763 ,  0.26731786,  0.1266551 ,  0.78960943,  0.900017  ,  0.02468355,  0.99110764,  0.40402032,  0.46224193,  0.44569296],
       [ 0.1509643 ,  0.26830514,  0.69337022,  0.1339183 ,  0.42711838,  0.0883597 ,  0.6923594 ,  0.01451872,  0.56684861,  0.46792245]])
```

**Solution:**

```
In [47]: df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(data, index=df.index))

In [48]: df
Out[48]:
       d         0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9
a b c
0 0 1  1  0.760215  0.920209  0.202057  0.038881  0.411661  0.675098  0.153514  0.009265  0.092980  0.729301
4 4 4  3  0.382296  0.881994  0.081530  0.083673  0.885485  0.503322  0.946521  0.833624  0.219431  0.093995
0 1 4  4  0.437439  0.794480  0.184309  0.315342  0.632299  0.809211  0.765709  0.098909  0.336043  0.929601
2 6 1  3  0.656176  0.267318  0.126655  0.789609  0.900017  0.024684  0.991108  0.404020  0.462242  0.445693
0 1 3  6  0.150964  0.268305  0.693370  0.133918  0.427118  0.088360  0.692359  0.014519  0.566849  0.467922
```